# Wifi keeps disconnecting on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04

I just made the switch from only windows to dualbooting with ubuntu, and I'm having some trouble getting all the necessary things working on my computer. Specifically, I'm having trouble with my wifi.

**The Problem:**
Every 5 to 15 minutes, my wifi will randomly loose connection, but the wifi meter at the top of the screen remains at about 80%. Manually disconnecting and reconnecting the wifi works, but doing so is frustrating, especially at the frequency with which the wifi dies. I've looked around the forums for a fix, but haven't really found one that is for my version of ubuntu, not to mention I don't really understand the solution. Apparently there is some command I need to run for the mods so they can figure out what is wrong, but I currently don't know what it is. My computer is a Lenovo with an AMD processor, I think its a G something.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your USB receiver built-in or is it a USB dongle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Mine is Lenovo G40. Check following

```
lspci -nn | grep Wireless
```

if it is RTL8723BE, following solution should work:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

When the terminal window opens, copy paste this in:

```
#Prevents the WiFi card from automatically sleeping and halting connection
options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0
```